# Faster way to find color range distributions in image?

Tags: python, opencv

The intent is to find and target blobs of different colors. This for now will be on a single core. It's a big image eg. 5 million pixels. This is a dumb way to do it and very slow "but it works" eg. takes 5 minutes to run obviously not practical. I don't know the colors in advance is the whole point, so I can't just put in a mask range.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('./image.jpg')
image_width = len(image)
image_height = len(image[0])

hsv_groups = {}

for x in range(image_width):
  for y in range(image_height):
    hsv_str_key = str(image[x][y])
    if hsv_str_key in hsv_groups:
      hsv_groups[hsv_str_key]  += 1
    else:
      hsv_groups[hsv_str_key] = 1

# to see distribution, can sort
print(json.dumps(hsv_groups))
```

After finding the highest HSV values I would then use these to apply to images and then work off the resulting areas(blobs).

I may be wrong about what value is in the image result eg. `[val, val, val]`, they may be RGB since you do that to HSV conversion usually before applying a mask.

One improvement is just comparing the arrays directly, seems to work. And checking if an array(even 1x3) is in a parent array works. I imagine the ideal solution is probably using numpy coupled with running straight c++/cython... although the iteration itself was pretty fast.

Comment: If you just want a histogram, use opencv's or numpy's or scikit-image's histogram functions.

Comment: haha is that what histogram means, anyway I will check that out/read up on it. Sounds like it's very easy then to get the highest color counts. thanks

Comment: Yep! A histogram is just a way to store the counts of each value.